# How can I scroll to a newly-added HubSection?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using a Hub to allow the user to drill down through hierarchical data. The Hub scrolls horizontally, and each HubSection contains a ListView of various items.

When a user taps an item, I add a new HubSection to the right. I would like the Hub to scroll to bring the new HubSection fully into view.

Doing this doesn't work:

```
myHub.Sections.Add(myNewHubSection);
myHub.ScrollToSection(myNewHubSection);
```

Adding a delay means it does ultimately scroll to the right position, so I suppose the problem is that the new HubSection hasn't rendered yet:

```
myHub.Sections.Add(myNewHubSection);
await Task.Delay(1000);
myHub.ScrollToSection(myNewHubSection);
```

I also tried measuring the HubSections and animating manually [as detailed here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/02/23/An-animated-ScrollToSection-for-the-Universal-Hub-Control.aspx), but that fails too for the same reason - the new HubSection still has zero size when it's just been added.

Is there a nicer way to do this? Animated would be much preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you subscribe to `myNewHubSection.Loaded` and trigger the `myHub.ScrollToSection()` there?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually call "UpdateLayout()" prior to calling scroll to section. This may force it to render and be able to scroll.

For the animation piece, this blog article has a good walkthrough:

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/02/23/An-animated-ScrollToSection-for-the-Universal-Hub-Control.aspx

Alternatively, if you can somehow know the offset, you can use the ScrollViewerExtensions from the [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit). It also provides extensions for the [AwaitableUI](http://awaitableui.codeplex.com/) library that could be used to wait for the new Hub Section to load.